# "Undercut someone's path"

Tags: word-usage

[In this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG3uCDXWNYw) the narrator is saying, from 1:29～

"President and Nielson will be meeting there tonight and though the president **undercut her path**, it seems by this point he is fed up."

From Merriam Unabridged, there are 8 meanings,

> transitive verb
>
> 1
>   :  to cut away the underpart of
>
> 2
>   :  to cut away material from the underside of (an object) so as to leave an overhanging portion in relief
>   
>   :  cut free from beneath
>
> 3
>   a :  to offer to sell at lower prices than or to work for lower wages or serve for lower fees than (a competitor)
>   b :  to accept or offer to accept a lower scale of (prices or wages) than is standard or general
>   c :  to have in gin rummy a count as low as or lower than the count of (the knocker)
>
> 4
>   a :  to cut (a book cover) in stamping with an improperly prepared die
>   b :  to hollow out or trim off a part of (a stamping die) to reduce impression pressure
>
> 5
>   :  to eat under laterally so as to leave without proper support — used of the action of etching acid on the lines of a printing surface
>
> 6
>   :  to cut obliquely into (a tree) below the main cut and on the side toward which the tree will fall
>
> 7
>   :  to strike (the ball) in golf, tennis, or hockey obliquely downward so as to give a backspin or elevation to the shot
>
> 8
>   :  to cut from (a forest) less timber than the growth warrants or less than the estimated annual cut

Which definition would this phrasal verb ? fall under and what could that mean?

Could this mean the president has not ear to listen to Keitjen Nielson?

I appreciate your support in advance.

Comment: What he says is "The president and Nielsen were meeting there tonight, and though the president has undercut her in the past, it seems by this point he was now fed up." Nielsen's first name is *Kirstjen*. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/undercut sense 2 is what seems to be pertinent (a figurative sense of the first definition Merriam-Webster gives).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought I saw an answer was made right after I had thrown this question but I am sorry I went out to go to dinner right after that. And I am sorry I thought the narrator is saying "Nielsen" too, but I was deluded by the word at the line beneath. And kindly let me have sometime to think, your suggestion that the definition 2 of your dictionary is right a bit makes me confused.

Comment: That answer was wrong anyway. The definition says it means "make weaker or less effective". I don't really follow US politics, but I'd say in this context it could mean he didn't approve of what she wanted to do in one way or another, and he therefore reduced her department's funding or some such, so as not to let her do her job the way she wanted to. I don't know the specifics of the situation or her job, though.

Comment: @user2684291 I appreciate your break down of the definition. Thank you.